# Validating login data PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to change my code from mysql_connect to PDO and I'm having some problems. I'm new to PHP and I was told that mysql_connect was old so here is my code. I can't seem to validate the user. Even If I enter a wrong user, it does not output the invalid user.

```
     $_GET['errorCode'];

        $errors = array(
      1 => 'Invalid User',
      2 => 'Incorrect Password');

      if(isset($_GET['errorCode'])){
      $code = $_GET['errorCode'];
      print isset($errors[$code]) ? $errors[$code] : 'Unknown error';
    }


         if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== 'POST'){


        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];




        if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){


              $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT password, salt FROM user WHERE username = :user_name");
         $stmt->execute(array(':user_name' => "$username"));
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);


        if(!$stmt->rowCount() > 0)

       {
        header('Location: index.php?errorCode=1');

        exit;

    }
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $hash = hash('sha256', $result['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
if($hash != $result['password']) //incorrect password
    {

      header('Location: index.php?errorCode=2');

       exit;
        }
        else
        {
            validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
            Header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
        } 
        }
           }
```

Comment: the best tutorial for switching over: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing `execute` statement, this is never going to work:

```
Header("Location: index.php");
$errmessage = "Invalid user";
print "<p id\"errmessage\"> $errmessage </p>";
exit;
```

As soon as you redirect, the browser will load `index.php` so you will never see your error message. You should **or** redirect **or** show an error message, but not both.

Comment: I have corrected that and I'm able to fix when the user enters an invalid user or password, but when the user enters the correct match it does not authenticate

Comment: @emurray You should post the current code below the original one.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to execute the statement - you just need to run `$stmt->execute();` after binding the params.

-- Edit --
And delete the line: `$userData = $dbh->query($stmt);`; your row will be fetched into `$result` with your current code.

Comment: I remove it on one of my testings but It still doesn't work with the  $stmt->execute(array(':user_name' => "$username"));

Comment: You can either pass the parameters to `->execute()` or bind them separately; doing both is redundant.  If you still get errors,  check them with `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo())`